# Database index that support arbitrary sort order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, database-indexes

Is there database index type (or data structure in general, not just *B-tree*) that provides efficient enumeration of objects sorted in arbitrarily customizable order?

In order to execute query like below efficiently

```
select *
from sample
order by column1 asc, column2 desc, column3 asc
offset :offset rows fetch next :pagesize rows only
```

DBMSes usually require composite index with the fields mentioned in "order by" clause with the same order and asc/desc directions. I.e.

```
create index c1_asc_c2_desc_c3_asc on sample(column1 asc, column2 desc, column3 asc)
```

The order of index columns does matter, and the index can't be used if the order of columns in "order by" clause does not match.

To make queries with every possible "order by" clause efficient we could create indexes for every possible combination of sort columns. But this is not feasible since the number of indexes depends on the number of sort columns exponentionally.
Namely, if *k* is the number of sort columns, *k!* will be the number of permutation of the sort columns, *2<sup>k</sup>* will be every possible combination of asc/desc directions, then the number of indexes will be *(k!·2<sup>(k-1)</sup>)*. (Here we use *2<sup>(k-1)</sup>* instead of *2<sup>k</sup>* because we assume that DBMS will be smart enough to use the same index in both direct and reverse directions, but unfortunately this doesn't help much.)

So, I wish to have something like

```
create universal index c1_c2_c3 on sample(column1, column2, column3)
```

that would have the same effect as *24 (k=3)* plain indexes (that cover every "order by"), but consume reasonable disk/memory space. As for reasonable disk/memory space I think that *O(k·n)* is ok, where *k* is the number of sort columns, *n* is the number of rows/entries and assuming that ordinary index consumes *O(n)*. In other words, universal index with *k* sort columns should consume approximately as much as *k* ordinary indexes.

What I want looks to me as *multidimensional indexes*, but when I googled this term I have found pages that relate to either

1. ordinary composite indexes - this is not what I need for obvious reason;
2. spatial structures like *k-d tree*, *quad/octo- tree*, *R-tree* and so on, which are more suitable for the nearest-neighbor search problem rather than sorting.

Comment: I'm not aware of a general solution to this problem. Note, though, that indices are mostly useful for ordering when they have a high discrimination value (e.g. an index on a `gender` column doesn't help much compared to its cost due to the small number of possible values, compared to e.g. an index on `name`). So in a practical application, the index permutations that are actually useful in the problem domain is usually far less than the theoretical maximum.

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is no general solution.  The work of maintaining such a beast would be extreme.  To solve this you'll have to know your problem domain and how you want to use your data.